# Symlink not linking hidden files

Tags: terminal, symlink, remote-server, public-html

I need to link the contents of a folder to my public_html folder.

If I use the following command:

```
ln -s ~/site/web/* ~/public_html/
```

The files are linked successfully but it doesn't link any hidden files i.e: .htaccess

If I use the following code:

```
ln -s ~/site/web/ ~/public_html/
```

It links the contents folder rather than just the files but it does link the hidden files within that folder. So my output is i.e: public_html/web/file1.html etc when it should be public_html/web/file1.html

Comment: have you tried with the full path (`ln -s /path/to/.hidden ~/public_html`)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Thank you, that does work, so I've now created the command: ln -s ~/site/web/* ~/public_html/ && ln -s ~/site/web/.htaccess ~/public_html which does copy all the files. I'm a little worried though as later on there may be more hidden files so that would mean I would need to go through them manually. Is there not a simoe command that would do this?

Comment: no worries glad it helped you :) and not that I'm aware of :S maybe you can do something using `find -type f` but can't promise anything :/ sorry

Comment: Me neither but as far as I can tell -s means symlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Thanks to @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I now have a code that does link all the files although, I have to manually tell it to link each hidden file.

Here's the code I used.

```
ln -s ~/site/web/* ~/public_html/ && ln -s ~/site/web/.htaccess ~/public_html
```

I will continue to look for a better way of doing it but for now it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Use ln -s ~/site/web/.* ~/public_html/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression that match both, all normal files and directories and the hidden ones.

To achieve that, you could try:

`ln -s ~/site/web/{*,.[aA-zZ]*} ~/public_html/`

Use the following line if you only want to match hidden files and directories:

`ln -s ~/site/web/{.[aA-zZ]*} ~/public_html/`